# How to get role definition for current user SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

With the following script I am retrieving all `role definitions` but how can I retrieve `role definitions` for current user only?

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
var roleDefinitionCollection;
var roleDefinition;


function permissionLevels() 
{
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) 
   {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();

        this.roleDefinitionCollection = web.get_roleDefinitions();
        clientContext.load(roleDefinitionCollection);
           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed))      
   }
}
function onQuerySucceeded() 
{
   var permissionLevel = 'Permission Levels:\n '
   var permissionLevelEnumerator = this.roleDefinitionCollection.getEnumerator();
   while (permissionLevelEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
       var roleDefinition = permissionLevelEnumerator.get_current();
        permissionLevel += roleDefinition.get_name() + '\n';
      }
    alert(permissionLevel);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For a specific site? Collection? Farm?

Comment: @Yugo for a specific site

Comment: That being the case, it's not an option to just click on check permissions for that user in the web ui?

Comment: when user opens a site or a page I want to retrieve his role definition and manipulate with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a JSOM call.. the info is already available

#### SharePoint has 37 types of permissions

They do not fit in a **32 bit integer**

So `webPermMasks` is divided over a **High** and **Low** integer, indicating which permissions a user has.

Each bit represents a permission, you can see the **bits** with:

```
(_spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.High).toString(2)
(_spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.Low).toString(2)
```

The SP.js library (available on most pages) has the info which Permission is which **bit number**

Run this in the developer console:

```
for (var permLevelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
    if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(permLevelName)) {
        var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(permLevelName);
           console.info(permLevelName,permLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

Note `permLevel` is **not** the **value**, it is the **bit-number**

`SP.PermissionKind.openItems` is bit-number **6** and thus value **2^6**

If you **add up** all the values you get the **High order** and **Low order** integer values for Permissions.

Note `permLevel` for `SP.PermissionKind.manageAlerts` is the **39th bit**

This is in the High order integer, so the value is **2^(39-31)**

#### webPermMasks

```
   _spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.Low
   _spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.High
```

Gives you **64 bits in TWO 32 bit Integers** (with 37 permissions only a few are used in the High order)

**indicating what *Permissions* the *Current User* has on the *Current Page***

### All PermissionKinds (SP.PermissionsKnd.[name])

Note: This is the **bit-number**, not the value!

To check if someone has permissions, 
You have to calculate the (summed) value then **binary** check against the High and Low order integers.

```
    viewListItems: 1
    addListItems: 2
    editListItems: 3
    deleteListItems: 4
    approveItems: 5
    openItems: 6
    viewVersions: 7
    deleteVersions: 8
    cancelCheckout: 9
    managePersonalViews: 10
    manageLists: 12
    viewFormPages: 13
    anonymousSearchAccessList: 14
    open: 17
    viewPages: 18
    addAndCustomizePages: 19
    applyThemeAndBorder: 20
    applyStyleSheets: 21
    viewUsageData: 22
    createSSCSite: 23
    manageSubwebs: 24
    createGroups: 25
    managePermissions: 26
    browseDirectories: 27
    browseUserInfo: 28
    addDelPrivateWebParts: 29
    updatePersonalWebParts: 30
    manageWeb: 31
    anonymousSearchAccessWebLists: 32
    useClientIntegration: 37
    useRemoteAPIs: 38
    manageAlerts: 39
    createAlerts: 40
    editMyUserInfo: 41
    enumeratePermissions: 63
```

#### Use in script

Or use the supplied function to check for individual levels:

```
  SP.PageContextInfo.get_webPermMasks().has( [bitnumber] );

  SP.PageContextInfo.get_webPermMasks().has( SP.PermissionKind.enumeratePermissions );
```

J1

Comment: I have created some new permission level and one of them I have called 'ES Employee' and I have assign some users to this permission. And when a user sign in I want to `alert()` in my case `You have: ES Employee permission`.

Comment: Then you have to learn how to get you custom profiledefinitions, I have never done that. Make it clear in your question also what you want.